# Como programar una sumatoria de dos variables en matlab

Tags: matemáticas, matlab

Basicamente estoy intentando programar

[image: Promedio móvil]

para la función, que posteriormente se le añade ruido aleatorio:

[image: Señal]

Cuando M toma valores de 5, 10 y 15.

Lo que he intentado es:

```
clear all

n = 0:0.16:20;
k = 0;
X = cos((5*pi/4)*(n-k)) + sin(2*pi*(n-k) + pi/4);
Xr = X + (1.5*rand(1,length(X)) - 0.75); % x[n] con ruido aleatorio
Xrl = zeros(1,length(Xr),15);

figure(1)
plot(n,X,'b',n,Xr,'r--o')
grid on
title 'X[n] vs Xr[n]'
xlabel 'n'
ylabel 'Amplitud'

for M=[5 10 15]
    for k = 0:M-1
        Xrp = Xr;
        Xrl(1,:,k+1) = Xrp;       
    end
    Y = (1/M)*sum(Xrl,3); % Suma sobre la tercera dim. de Xrl por 1/M
    figure(2)
    plot(n,Y)
    hold on
end
```

El problema es que devuelve la gráfica de la figura 2 como una linea sólida, lo cual implicaría ajuste perfecto para cualquier M. Lo cual es extraño, mi teoría es que no esta evaluando para la variable k.

De antemano gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta al asignar `Xrp` a `Xrl`. Al asignarlo directamente sin basicamente lo estas copiando repetidamente M veces. Despues al sumarlo y al dividirlo por M, estas recibiendo el mismo valor.

Lo que tienes que hacer es desfazar `k` posiciones en cada asignacion de 'Xrp', para que la suma te incluya los M valores previos de `Xrp`. Esto lo puedes hacer con el comando `circshift`

```
 Xrl(1,:,k+1) = circshift(Xrp,[0,k]);
```